# field validator which does not allow to move to the next field

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, validation

I need a field validator which does not allow to user to move to the next field if there is an error. I tried the asp validator and jquery validator which allows to move to the next field.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.class').focusout(function(){
    if (!isValid($(this).value)){
        $(this).focus();
    } 
});


function isValid(inp){
    return inp !== undefined && inp.length !== 0;
}
```

​

See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/albertjan/vhzL4/

if textbox is empty: http://jsfiddle.net/albertjan/vhzL4/6/

$('.class').focus() not working on ff is known see: [Javascript focus and select not working in FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562723/javascript-focus-and-select-not-working-in-ff)

Comment: I want is that if the textbox is empty the focus should not move to the next textbox.

Comment: just check wether or not inp is null or "" in the `isValid` method

Comment: Thanks that I got, but i dont want the focus to move to the next textbox until the first one is filled.

Comment: check the second link isn't that what you want?

Comment: the focus is moving to the next textbox even if the first textbox is empty. I don't want the focus to leave the first textbox if it is empty

Comment: Thanks, It works when i checked it in chrome. But why does it not work in firefox