# Firefox 17 focus selectbox not working

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Im trying to capture keypresses from an input and then focussing an  element.

```
<input id="asdfasfd1" />
<input id="asdfasfd2" />

<select id="currency"><option>bla</option></select>

​$(function() {

   var currencyElement = $('#currency');

   $('#asdfasfd1').bind('keypress', function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      currencyElement.focus();
   });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KkXwT/6/ works in IE 8,9,10 and Chrome 23 but not in Firefox 17, does some know why its not working?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562723/javascript-focus-and-select-not-working-in-ff or this http://www.weberforums.com/topic11544.html

Comment: the jsfiddle you provided works perfectly for me. when i press any key in the first text box, the combo gets focus. i have firefox 17.0.1 on a mac.

Comment: behnil this is an selectbox not an input box, its not working on Firefox 17 running windows 8

Comment: Its working... Check this.. http://jsfiddle.net/KkXwT/21/

Comment: In FF the focus event fires but no visual change is made to the select (unlike Chrome) which highlights it.

Comment: @MrCode yeah, seems like FF doesn't have any visual change on select unlike Chrome or IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working... Check this.. jsfiddle.net/KkXwT/21

In FireFox there is no highlight that makes you feel it as focused.
I have made something for you to realize that its focused.

Comment: Yeah, i should look if i can style it so there is an visual thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, Happy to be Helpful... :)